# Upgrading the Java Version and iText

Tags: java, itext, upgrade

we are using a very old version of java installed previously in our server (version 1.4) and according to this case we used a very old version of iText2.1

Our main vendors planned to upgrade the server and they will upgrade the java version to 8.

**Question: should i upgrade my application which uses the iText2.1, or it will work fine with the new Java ver.? and what version should i use then?**

*Note:i've tried to raise this question in the itext blog but they put the stackoverflow link for any technical question. , so please be kind and help me.*

Comment: SO is not the support site for iText. https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: @LutzHorn what is that?

Comment: A link. Did you read what is written on the linked page?

Comment: @LutzHorn on the contrary, SO *is* the support site for iText. I quote from the page you linked: "Stack Overflow works really well for technical support and we welcome this, within limits." - "Types of questions and where to ask:

How do I? -- Stack Overflow (tell them what tags to use -- your product and language at minimum)
I got this error, why? -- Stack Overflow".
iText Software also actively monitors SO for any iText-related questions.

Comment: @BDeveloper "I tried to raise this question in the iText blog" - that would be http://itextpdf.com/node? We did not enable comments on our website, but questions like yours are best suited for SO, since you are not a customer. Customers have access to to our JIRA.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse So the company you work for offloads the support for people who don't pay you to SO?

Comment: @lutzhorn If you use the Stack Exchange queries to find who answered the most questions tagged "itext", you will see that the top users are either employees of iText Software,  or some of our most valued users which whom we have good ties. It's also the other way around. We go where our users go. 10 years ago that was Sourceforge, since a couple of years it's StackOverflow. If iText become popular on the next best Q&A site, we will follow our users there too. That being said, paying customers have access to our JIRA.

Comment: @LutzHorn We used to use lists.sourceforge.net for non-paying users up until 3 years and 6 months ago. Then we slowly moved to StackOverflow. What's the problem with that? As Amedee says: we move to where the users are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above comment is really an answer:

> I know that in recent versions of iText (I think 5.5.7 or 5.5.8) we made some small changes for Java 7 and Java 8. The minimum for iText 5.x.x is Java 5. Anything older than 5.0.0 is totally unsupported, sorry. iText 2.1.0 is from March 2008, that's 8 years ago.

Comment: Even though it's unsupported, I recommend that the OP tries to do a test upgrade in a virtual machine or a Docker container. It *may* work just out of the box, who knows? You don't know if you don't try.

Comment: the conclusion is that if i didn't upgrade the iText version it would throws some exception, right?!

Comment: It *might* throw an exception. It depends. I found 2 recent commits that were about Java 7 and 8: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/commit/4c1a55977a and https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/commit/8ba0064e19. Do you want to be 100% sure? We can only 100% guarantee that recent versions work on Java 8. Anything else is a gamble.

Comment: thanks a lot @AmedeeVanGasse for your patience and support

Answer (score 1):

Using Eclipse 
      I am Using **1.8_45** with **iText5.7**

```
  No Exception and warning with it . 
  So Upgrade
```

and if you are not upgrade your iText2.1 with java 1.8_45 
so  it's give you Exception

Comment: thank you for your answer. actually all i needed is to know if we need to upgrade our application (which means upgrading the iText Version ) once the vendor of our server upgrade the Java ver. i wanted to know is this upgrade would affect on my application or not!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can easily upgrade your versions

1.8_45 to 66 jdk

with

iText5.7

Comment: what if i didn't upgrade my iText version, would it work with the new version of Java or it would throw some exceptions and warning about some methods that is not used any more in the new vers. of iText. in my opinion it would be affected and it wont work fine, but another member sees the opposite ... any help?

Comment: Did you try to *not* upgrade iText?

Comment: we need to know before the upgrade starts to put our time plan.

Comment: @BDeveloper Well, we do not know your application and how you *use* iText. We can not do you planning for you.

Comment: I know that in recent versions of iText (I think 5.5.7 or 5.5.8) we made some small changes for Java 7 and Java 8. The minimum for iText 5.x.x is Java 5. Anything older than 5.0.0 is totally unsupported, sorry. iText 2.1.0 is from March 2008, that's 8 years ago.

Comment: @LutzHorn i didn't ask to do the plan for me. that's why i am asking before writing my concerns about the upgrading process. would this upgrade affect on my application performance and do i HAVE to upgrade as well!

Comment: @BDeveloper Apart from the technical reasons to upgrade, there are also legal reasons: Read [Can iText 2.1.7 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially) You should start planning an upgrade of your software using iText.